# jquery ui combobox set selected item with variable as selector name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, selecteditem

This one problem has been driving me mad lately. In a .each() I'm looping through select elements and converting them to jquery ui comboboxes. That works fine. When it comes to setting the selected value I'm having a problem. In my same .each() I'm trying to set the selected valueto a value I get elsewhere.

```
 $("#" + e + " [role='select']").each(function () {
  $(this).combobox();
  var selId = '#ContactCategoryId';
  var cellv = '9';
  $(selId+" option[value=" + cellv + "]").attr("selected", 'true');
 });
```

Now that code above works perfectly, sets the combobox to the value of 9 and text value of "Cell Number". Now the below code fails, no errors but doesn't change the selected value. I need it to work in the below fashion with me getting the Id from the current select element: $(this).attr('id'). I've tried so many different things, please can someone show me the light here.

```
$("#" + e + " [role='select']").each(function () {

  $(this).combobox();
  var selId = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
  var cellv = '9';
  $(selId+" option[value=" + cellv + "]").attr("selected", 'true');
});
```

I'm using JQuery 1.7 and the latest JQuery UI,Thanx!

James

---

Due to my reputation I wasn't able to asnwer my own question so here is my solution:

OK this issue really annoyed me now after finding the solution. Normally when I have issues with jquery plugins I just look at the source and play around with that but for this issue I didn't try and it cost me. Here's the solution, so simple as the answer quite often is.

```
        $("#" + e + " [role='select']").each(function () {
             if($(this).css('display')=='none')
             {
                 $(this).combobox("destroy");
             }
             $(this).combobox();
        });
```

When looking at the source I thought come now, it must get its value from somewhere. So I manually set the value:

```
              $(this).val('9')
```

It worked on the first opening of the form but not the second then I realised the I needed to destroy it if it existed and then create the combobox. I'm sure one you guru's have a better solution but I'm glad I got this working

Comment: `$(this)` is probably not what you think it is .... can you post all of your code ?

Comment: Hey ManseUK, thanx. Yeah I thought that might be the issue but if I can actually log to the console that exact value of the variable selId it is the name of my select. I've updated my original question

Comment: to select an option you should do `$('select').val('9');` so in your case `$(this).val(cellv)` have you tried that ?

Comment: yeah doesn't work hey. I don't know why it doesn't work when retrieving the id with $(this).attr('id'). I'm going to setup a jsfiddle quick

Comment: Ok - i think i see a problem ... your using `$('#blah').each(` the `#` is an `id` selector - ids should be unique on the document

Comment: Don't think it could be that. The "e" is a formId and within that form I have a html table with rows and cells with controls in them.All the select controls in this form have that attribute "role=select". When debugging or logging the actual element to the console ( console.log($(this));  ) you can see its the select element I'm working with

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of something similar. Seems like there might be something else wrong : http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/a9F6J/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not as straightforward as imagined because the combobox is not actually a `select` element ...updating the combobox element updates the select element but not the other way around ... the only way I can see of doing it is to destroy the combobox and recreate it ... this works :

```
$("#divselect").children('select').each(function() {

    $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
    var cellv = '0'; // new value

    // Destroy the combobox
    $this.combobox("destroy");

    // Unselect the currently selected option
    $("option:selected",$this).removeAttr("selected");

    // Select the option you want to select
    $("option[value='"+cellv+"']",$this).attr("selected", "selected");

    // Create the combobox again
    $this.combobox();

});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9F6J/58/)

Also Note .. you do not have to do this :

```
$("#showAnyCity").click(function() {
    checkdiv();
});
```

you can do this

```
$("#showAnyCity").click(checkDiv);
```

Comment: Thanx for the feedback ManseUK, appreciate it. Yeah in my updated answer I realised eventually that the combobox would never recreate itself after initial creation so I followed your same path of destroying it.